# Twitter APK only sending 140 characters?

Tags: swift, twitter

Does anyone know if TwitterKit for iOS is still only fetching 140 characters for tweets instead of the updated count? I am putting text into a UILabel with dynamic properties that should resize itself but I am still getting truncated tweets.[image]

For the more curious, I am also using the following code to get the JSON:

```
    public func fetchTweets(_ handler: @escaping ([Tweet]) -> Void) {
    fetch { results in
        var tweets = [Tweet]()
        var tweetArray: NSArray?
        if let dictionary = results as? NSDictionary {
            if let tweets = dictionary[TwitterKey.tweets] as? NSArray {
                tweetArray = tweets
            } else if let tweet = Tweet(data: dictionary) {
                tweets = [tweet]
            }
        } else if let array = results as? NSArray {
            tweetArray = array
        }
        if tweetArray != nil {
            for tweetData in tweetArray! {
                if let tweet = Tweet(data: tweetData as? NSDictionary) {
                    tweets.append(tweet)
                }
            }
        }
        handler(tweets)
    }
}

    public func fetch(_ handler: @escaping (PropertyList?) -> Void) {
    performTwitterRequest("GET", handler: handler)
}

    func performTwitterRequest(_ method: String, handler: @escaping (PropertyList?) -> Void) {
   Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID {

    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
        let jsonExtension = (self.requestType.range(of: Constants.JSONExtension) == nil) ? Constants.JSONExtension : ""
        let url = "\(Constants.twitterURLPrefix)\(self.requestType)\(jsonExtension)"
        var clientError : NSError?
            let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: method, url: url, parameters: parameters, error: &clientError)
        sendTwitterRequest(client: client, request: request, handler: handler)

}

func sendTwitterRequest(client: TWTRAPIClient, request: URLRequest, handler: @escaping (PropertyList?) -> Void) {
    client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, responseData, error) -> Void in
        if let err = error {
            print("Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
         var propertyListResponse: PropertyList?
        if responseData != nil {
            propertyListResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: .mutableLeaves)
            if propertyListResponse == nil {
                let error = "Couldn't parse JSON response."
                self.log(error)
                propertyListResponse = error
            }
        }  else {
            let error = "No response from Twitter."
            self.log(error)
            propertyListResponse = error
        }
        self.synchronize {
            self.captureFollowonRequestInfo(propertyListResponse)
        }
        handler(propertyListResponse)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re manually calling the Twitter API endpoint to fetch an array of Tweets, so you’ll need to add the `tweet_mode=extended` parameter to the call in order to fetch longer Tweets up to 280 characters.

Comment: Great! Got it! Also, the JSON is now called full_text. Funny story though: The first result in my table view actually still had an "..." and I almost cried. Turns out is was a user typed ellipsis because I scrolled down and saw full length entries.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at this answer from a somewhat similar question.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40429448/8930099

- On iOS, a URL counts as 23 characters no matter the original length of the URL.
- On iOS, an image counts as 23 characters no matter what size it is.
- Therefore, with an image and URL, we have only 94 characters
  available on iOS per Tweet. And there’s nothing that can be done
  about it unless Twitter updates their SDK or Apple updates SLComposeViewController.

Comment: As far as I know, 140 characters is still the basic rule of a Tweet.